# meaning of $z^*$ (Complex number)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Solve the equation $z+2z^*=\frac{15}{2+i}$.

I want to ask what's the meaning of $z^*$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it means $\bar z$ the complex conjugate of z

Comment: What is $z$ here?

Comment: You are asked to find it, it's like solving and equation for x, but now z is a complex number ie $z = a + ib$ so $z^* = a - ib$

Comment: ;), if you don't need anymore assistant you can mark this answered !

Answer (score 2):

Write $z=x+iy$ then $z^•=x-iy$ and $z+2z^*=3x-iy$ and our equation looks like

$$3x-iy={15\over 5}(2-i)=6-3i$$

and so $z=2+3i$

Comment: Um, $z+z^*=2x$, not $2x-iy$. The $iy$s cancel.

Comment: I edit thanks @Akiva Weinberger

Comment: Then $z+2z^*=(x+iy)+(2x-2iy)=3x-iy$.